# How to set variable values of fluid template in a static extension typoscript?

Tags: typo3, typoscript, typo3-extensions

I have some pages and I want to set a couple of variables in the fluid template. Each variable should have another value depending on the current page. I know how to perform this with the typoscript of the page itself. But I should do it in my extension and include it as a static typoscript.

I tried to include a static script with page.10.variables{...} and then setting the values. If I do so with the native setup script from the page it works fine. But trying this within a static script from my extension, it does't.

Edit:

The pages have all the same standard fluid layout. For example:

on page 1: var1 = "String A1", var2 = "String A2"...
on page 2: var1 = "String B1", var2 = "String B2"...
...

Comment: You can pass argument to typoscript object with data attribute, [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43777699/5961782) is nice explanation could help you. Thanks to @Nitori!

Comment: Thank you, but I want exactly the opposite way. There is a standard fluid layout and I don't know on template level which strings to take for a list labels. For example:<label>{firstString}</label> shows on page 1<label>Name A</label>; on page 2 it shows <label>Name B</label>.

Comment: if you include static script from your extension, don't you get anything from the typoscript, or don't work the conditions? How do you build the conditions to differ between different pages?

Comment: I don't get anything from the typoscript. I tried to differ by using the uid of the page: [ 5 in tree.rootLineIds ]

Comment: Is it possible that the static TypoScript gets overwritten? Check the final TypoScript in Object Browser and the order in the Template Analyzer (both in Template module)

Comment: Thank you for answer - there are more burning things to do now, but I will check this as soon as possible.